# Adding a webServer handler causes duplicate key error in IISExpress when virtual path specified

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, web-config, iis-express, handlers

I have an MVC5 app in VS2013. I need to add some handlers to the root Web.config. This works fine with no virtual directory, but when I specify a virtual directory, IIS Express fails.

This is easy to reproduce in VS2013:

- Create a new ASP.NET Web Application. Select MVC and no authentication
- edit the top level `Web.config`. Add the following lines to the bottom, right before the closing configuration tag:

  ```
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add verb="GET" path="*.png" name="Static for png" 
                                     type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```
- The application will run fine. Now, go to the Project properties, "Web" tab, and add an application name like "WebTest" to the project Url. Click the "Create Virtual Directory" button and acknowledge so that VS will let you save.
- build and run

You get an error 500.19 - *Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Static for png'* .

IIS Express is running the app at two URLs, one with the name and one without. The URL without the name (http://localhost:52065/) comes first and works fine; the one with the name comes second and has the error. By the way, VS2010 just runs the app with the name and this works fine.

Poking in the `MyDocuments\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` file, I see the two entries for the app, both pointing to the same physical directory:

```
<site name="WebTest" id="3">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\_Dev\WebTest\WebTest" />
  </application>
  <application path="/WebTest" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\_Dev\WebTest\WebTest" />
  </application>
```

I don't understand why there need to be two entries. I tried:

- removing the first application entry. This causes an unrecognized
  configuration path error.
- duplicating the entire solution, and pointing the first entry at it. This gets the same duplicate error.

Some Context: I need the static handlers because this app has to be structured as a collection of independent dlls. I embed the content into the dlls
at build time and then use a `VirtualPathProvider` to intercept each path request and return a stream from the dll. I've found that this only works if the static file handler is in the root Web.config; otherwise my VPP doesn't get the request.

The dlls are in a `Plugin` directory under the project root directory. Putting a config file there didn't help either.

What am I missing? Is there a way to get IIS Express to run the app only with a name and avoid the duplicate key error?

Comment: I would very much like to know how to properly avoid this as well.  A band-aid solution is to remove the duplicate keys before they are added (e.g. <remove name="Static for png" />) in the web.config.

Comment: Yup .. that's the only solution I've found as well. It's surprising to me that more people haven't documented the same problem and had a better solution emerge. Especially since this is an artifact of the newer dev server and doesn't happen in VS2010. Are we asking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

You must always keep in mind, that ASP.NET applications under the same web site inherit parent's configuration. That means, the WebTest application will have one "Static for png" from itself, and another "Static for png" from its parent (the site root application).

Thus, as @hobwell pointed out, you must add a  tag to avoid duplication.